# Issues with Visual C++ 2013, TFS & property sheets

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, tfs

### Background

I am currently working on a Visual Studio 2013 solution, contining ~190 C++ projects. Since they are all modules of the same ecosystem, they have lots of properties in common (common linking options, binaries output location, post build steps, etc).

As such, we have created a set of property sheets, enabling us to maintain these properties in a centralized way.

This works fine.

Our team uses TFS as an SCM, and the Visual Studio integration with TFS *for property sheets* seems to be lacking (or maybe it's just buggy or unconfigured).

### The problems

1. When editting a property sheet (that is present in TFS), Visual Studio attempts to save it, which fails with an error message. Clicking on Apply/OK again, will correctly store the changes in the PS in memory, but the property sheet will not be saved until the solution is closed (performing a checkin doesn't see the changes causing developers to make two commits for a change, resulting in non-transactional commits).
2. If I perform a checkout from within the Solution Explorer, property sheet changes are never checked in; they always end up in the "Excluded Changes" in the TFS commit window, and cause a lot of problems when developers are not attentive to this.
3. Scenario: developer A creates a feature branch, adds a project with a property sheet, does a few commits, then merges back into the main branch, deletes the feature branch and everybody gets the code. Then we discover that the property sheet was never added in TFS (visual studio doesn't add it by itself when it's added to the project) and since developer A deleted her local branch files, the file is lost; This means lost work and efforts made to write the PS again.

### The question(s)

What can be done to customize TFS treatment of various file types (like property sheets)?

Are there any tools for Visual Studio or TFS that improve/automate this integration? (I know SO is not big on tool recommendations, but I am more interested in finding out if the functionality exists at all, rather than getting speciffic tool names).

Thanks.

Comment: I just edit project files and property sheets with the plain XML editor. Good luck :/

Comment: @BillyONeal, the problem isn't the editting, it is the policies that are set as default, for dealing with property sheets in TFS integrated projects.

Comment: @utnapistm: I don't understand what you mean by "policies". I don't use the VS property sheets editor at all, so there are no policies.

Comment: @BillyONeal, I mean how property sheets are handled when the project is integrated with TFS.

Comment: What does TFS have to do with anything? If you use the XML editor it has no problem checking things out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Is the property sheet within the scope of your project or is it added as a loose file? It could very well be that when you perform a check-in or check-out that the file cannot be changed because the TFS does not see it as a part of the project. If you right click on the project in your solution explorer you should see an option to add files. This is the only way to get it into the scope of your project.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot add the property sheet to the project files. When I try to do so, VS just tells me that the name cannot be added because it is invalid. I think it is because the property sheet is already in use for the project (as it is inherited by the project).